# Gmail filter causing duplicate message to be sent to my inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have set a filter on my Gmail to ensure that all messages sent from the company website do not get marked as spam.  The have the words `[Rhythm Time]` in the subject so are easy to identify.

However, now if I send an e-mail with those same words in the subject, it copies the email to my inbox as well as sending it to the person in the "to" box.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the NOT (*minus*) operator in your filter to remove when you are the sender:

```
from:(-iamthesender@gmail.com) subject:[Rhythm Time]
```